# Search using multiple criteria in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to search particular data using multiple criteria. I am using age,location, type as multiple search criteria. If the age is 6-12 and type is outdoor only the particular criteria as to be displayed . In the below code it searches if age group is 6-12 and location is oudoor it displays value of age 6-12 and 12-18 whose location is outdoor.It as to be search even if only 1 criteria i.e age or location or type is entered.

Here is the code

```
<?php
 $username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$db = "game";

    // Connect to server and select database.
    $conn=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password)or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db($db,$conn)or die("cannot select DB");
     if(!$conn)
     {
         die("cannot connect");
     }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{


$name=$_POST["name"];
$age=$_POST["age"];
$location=$_POST["location"];
$type=$_POST["type"];




 $query = "SELECT * FROM `game1` WHERE age ='$age' or location='$location' or type='$type'";



$run = mysql_query($query);


if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
header("Location: gamesearch1.php?age=$age&location=$location&type=$type");
}

else {

    echo "<script>alert('No members Yet!')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: First of all, stop usming `mysql_` - This functions are deprecated and not longer supported in PHP7. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO_` instead. Also, you should visit http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection. Your code is not safe at all and your database can be hacked in a few seconds without the need of any deep knowledge. Also, can you tell us how the value of `$_POST["age"]` looks exactly?

Comment: Your text says **and**, your SELECT says **or**. Please decide what you want and then rewrite your question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `AND` instead of `OR` for your criteria. And you should really use parametrized query!

Comment: If I select age group 6-12 and dont select any other criteria it as to display value. So OR is used insted of AND

Comment: If there the querry Argument could be empty you can use something like this   SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%$searchterm%' and then as suggested use AND istead of OR

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM `game1` WHERE age LIKE %$age% and location LIKE '%$location%' and type LIKE '%$type%'";

Comment: I used it above way. It doent display anything

Comment: It working thanks.